# How to stop errors generated by zone.js in browser console?

Tags: angular, typescript, zone.js

Here is my code in the httpService.ts

```
public HttpPost(url: string, data: any): Observable<Response> 
{
    let headers = new Headers();
    let reqOpts = new RequestOptions();
    headers.append(AUTH_CONTENT_TYPE_KEY, AUTH_CONTENT_TYPE);
    if (this.Token) {
        headers.append(AUTH_HEADER_KEY, AUTH_TOKEN_PREFIX + this.Token);
    }
    reqOpts.headers = headers;
    return this.http.post(url, data, reqOpts).timeout(30000).map((res: Response) => res)
        .catch((err: Response) => { return Observable.throw(err) });
}
```

If I try to using this service to call an API like this way:

```
this.httpService.HttpPost(url, data).subscribe(
    (res: any) => 
    {
       // do something
    },
    (error: any) => 
    {
        if (error.status === 409)
            // do something
        else if (error.status === 401)
            // do something
        else
           // do something
    }
);
```

and if the res status code is one other than 200, such as 401, 403 or 409, then these kind of annoying errors are generated by zone.js in console. (sorry for hide part url of APIs)

[image]

So is there anyway to stop zone.js to generate such a kind of annoying errors in console, tried to google for a solution with example but not found yet, Thanks!

tried to use this in main.ts but not worked:

```
window.console.error = function() {};
```

Edit: add stack trace:

[image]

Comment: Please provide the given stack trace (click on the arrow before "POST").

Comment: ok I added the stack trace

Answer (score 12):

When a network request fails, Chrome shows the error in the console. The error displays the url that failed, the HTTP status received and the origin of the request. Usually, in Angular, you're making an HTTP request in response to some action from the user. Angular captures those actions using zones, so, almost any error has its origin in `zone.js`. If you check the whole stack trace, however, you'll see that the error happens after calls to your own code. It's just that is code in `zone.js` what ends up calling that code.

So, the only way not to see request errors in the console, is to configure your chrome console to ignore them, but I don't think there is a programmatic way of doing so.

I'm sure you're thinking about `window.onerror`, which in theory captures any uncaught exception. But those network errors are not JavaScript exceptions, so you won't be able to capture them.

I'd wouldn't replace `console.error`. because if you do, you won't be able to see true errors you might have in your code. Anyway, as stated, in this case is Chrome who is writing to the console, and the only way to hide those errors is, as I already said, filtering them (but it'll only work for you, of course).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, there aint any functional issues but just these annoying errors in console if res code is not 200. I have considered about letting the backend give 200 if the API is working, and just give the real error code in res body then error wont generated, but may lots of code change in backend side, or maybe some custom error handler is that possible.

Answer (score 11):

In Dev mode, you can add the following line to import zone-error in `src/environments/environment.ts`

```
import `zone.js/dist/zone-error`;
```

Then most of zone related error stack trace will gone.

Comment: Although, it won't help with that case.
Also backticks should be replaced with single/double quotes in the import statement.

Comment: In Production mode, comment it

Comment: add the import only to `environment.ts` - not to `environment.prod.ts`

Comment: Using Angular 11+, this import doesn't remove errors since it is now thrown by `zone-evergreen.js`

Comment: @Sixteen - were you able to resolve this in Angular v11?